# showing progress dialog while inflating views

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a situation where my app does some fairly convoluted view inflation at run time and I want to notify the user that something's happening so they don't think the app is just stuck for a second or two.  The problem is that both the PD and the inflation are both happening on the display thread, so, the PD usually just flashes on and off (if at all) when the inflation is finished.

I'm wondering what I can do to make sure that the app first displays the PD before moving on to the inflation process.  I can't see any way to thread this since both operations are happening on the display thread, though perhaps I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: "I have a situation where my app does some fairly convoluted view inflation at run time and I want to notify the user that something's happening so they don't think the app is just stuck for a second or two" -- that makes no sense. What did Traceview show you is really taking up the time?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Traceview, I'll look into it now.  The app just pauses for a couple of seconds (stops reacting) while it's inflating the views and performing some logical operations on how to draw them. It's not a huge delay, but in my opinion it's too long to leave a user without some feedback that *something is going on.  I'll Google Traceview. I assume it's some sort of profiler that I can use to get better visibility as to what's going on beneath the hood?

Comment: Yes: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html